# node.js / socket.io, cookies only working locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use cookie based sessions, however it'll only work on the local machine, not over the network. If I remove the session related stuff, it will however work just great over the network...

You'll have to forgive the lack of quality code here, I'm just starting out with node/socket etc etc, and finding any clear guides is tough going, so I'm in n00b territory right now. Basically this is so far hacked together from various snippets with about 10% understanding of what I'm actually doing...

The error I see in Chrome is:

> socket.io.js:1632GET http://192.168.0.6:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1334431940273 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Socket.handshake ------- socket.io.js:1632
>
> Socket.connect ------- socket.io.js:1671
>
> Socket ------- socket.io.js:1530
>
> io.connect ------- socket.io.js:91
>
> (anonymous function) ------- /socket-test/:9
>
> jQuery.extend.ready ------- jquery.js:438

And in the console for the server I see:

> debug - served static content /socket.io.js
>
> debug - authorized
>
> warn  - handshake error No cookie

My server is:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , connect = require('express/node_modules/connect')
  , parseCookie = connect.utils.parseCookie
  , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express)
  , sessionStore = new RedisStore();

app.listen(8080, '192.168.0.6');

app.configure(function()
{
    app.use(express.cookieParser());

    app.use(express.session(
    {
        secret: 'YOURSOOPERSEKRITKEY',
        store: sessionStore
    }));
});

io.configure(function()
{
    io.set('authorization', function(data, callback)
    {
        if(data.headers.cookie)
        {
            var cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);

            sessionStore.get(cookie['connect.sid'], function(err, session)
            {
                if(err || !session)
                {
                    callback('Error', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    data.session = session;
                    callback(null, true);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            callback('No cookie', false);
        }
    });
});

var users_count = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    console.log('New Connection');

    var session = socket.handshake.session;

    ++users_count;

    io.sockets.emit('users_count', users_count);

    socket.on('something', function(data)
    {
        io.sockets.emit('doing_something', data['data']);
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function()
    {
        --users_count;

        io.sockets.emit('users_count', users_count);
    });

});
```

My page JS is:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.6', { port: 8080 } );

    socket.on('users_count', function(data)
    {
        $('#client_count').text(data);
    });

    socket.on('doing_something', function(data)
    {
        if(data == '')
        {
            window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                $('#target').text(data);
            }, 3000);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#target').text(data);
        }
    });

    $('#textbox').keydown(function()
    {
        socket.emit('something', { data: 'typing' });
    });

    $('#textbox').keyup(function()
    {
        socket.emit('something', { data: '' });
    });

});
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, however, only when using Chrome. My app works fine in Safari. Do you have the same situation? I'm not sure what the solution is.

Answer (score 1):

Check your system clock, if the server and client have different clocks, the cookie may be immediately expiring right after you set it.

Comment: Checked the clocks and they seem fine - cookies are usually fine with other stuff too

Comment: Well it seems that data.headers.cookie does not exist. Can you dump the request headers to see what is going on?